# How do I prevent Google Chrome from blocking my popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup, popup-blocker

On my website there is a button that just used to call a function that calls `window.open`, however, recently an adjustment was needed to do a server-side check before the popup was opened.

Ever since the code was added that does the AJAX call, browsers blocks the popup, that is opened in the `success` callback of the AJAX call. I read that browsers might block the popup if it's not called by a user click event, so I tried setting the AJAX request to `async: false`, which solved the problem in Firefox, but Google Chrome still keeps blocking my popup. Is there any way to get around this?

I could move the server-side check to the page that gets opened in the popup, but I'd like to do it before opening the popup, if possible.

Code:

```
<a id="attackButton" href="#">Attack Base!</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#attackButton').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + '/index.php?option=com_pbbgs&format=raw&getinfo=goingame',
            data: { 'gameid': 618 },
            dataType: 'text',
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                eval(data);

                if (window.gameURL) {
                    goingameRaw();
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});

function goingameRaw()
{
    window.open(window.gameURL,'test','left=20,top=20,width=1024,height=640,toolbar=0,resizable=0,location=0');
}
</script>
```

Example response body:

```
window.gameURL="http://mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_pbbgs&format=raw&startgame=618&width=1024&height=640";checktutorial('js','attack');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid browser popup blockers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, popups should be a direct result of a user action. Doing them in ajax callback will not do the trick. Also, using `async:false` is bad - in FF it is known to block the whole browser. Think of some other way to do the check:

- it could be the first thing you do in the popup
- you can open the popup on click and manipulate it later when the callback fires
- you can require the user to click again some button to trigger the popup (probably the worst solution)
- you can do it on page load

Comment: I suspected as much, thanks. I implemented your second suggestion.

Comment: There is a good example here http://theandystratton.com/2012/how-to-bypass-google-chromes-javascript-popup-blocker

Comment: @Emil Why is number 3 the worst? One click on a Javascript confirm when the UI is out of sync with the logged in state because the user has hit the back button or something? I'm going to try it.

Comment: Yeah I agree it sucks.

Comment: @Emil Ivanov. Second option worked for me.i.e opening window first then manipulate.thanks.

Comment: @Emi lvanov: in my case 1st  page showing window.open null but in another page its showing window.open properly open .i am understand why its occur?

Answer (score 23):

Following up on Emil's excellent answer, "you can open the popup on click and manipulate it later when the callback fires".  I used this implementation.

```
$('#attackButton').click(function() {
```

New code here

```
    var win = window.open('');
    window.oldOpen = window.open;
    window.open = function(url) { // reassignment function
        win.location = url;
        window.open = oldOpen;
        win.focus();
    }
```

end new code

```
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + '/index.php',
        data: { 'gameid': 618 },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            window.open('some url'); // will call reassignment function above 
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: There is no need to have add a global variable 'oldOpen' and overload the native global 'open'. This is all within the same closure, the scope chain is perfectly fine. Just create a local function "myWinGo" or whatever and use that.

Comment: That's a good point for this example.  However, if the window.open call is in a library that you don't want to change or if you want to leave calls as window.open for readability, then overriding is a good choice.

Comment: Wow, genius little function!  It even restores the window.open afterwards.

Comment: I get a blank new tab as soon as `var win = window.open('');` is executed. Ideally, I want the new window to open only in the ajax success.

Comment: @BenjaminCrouzier Unfortunately that sort of window popup disconnected from the user click seems to be what Chrome blocks.

Comment: @BenjaminCrouzier After calling `win = window.open()` you can call `window.focus()` and then, if the ajax fails, `win.close()`. That way, the user shouldn't be annoyed by the popup.

Answer (score 5):

You can open a window that is not blocked just under the onclick event, if you open it on ajax call it is considered popup. However I used this method with success for some time to open a popup and not be blocked.

http://en.nisi.ro/blog/development/javascript/open-new-window-window-open-seen-chrome-popup/

Comment: Dead link! These kinds of answers are highly discouraged on SO, for this reason in particular.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a vanilla JavaScript [solution](https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-open-url-in-new-tab), I am using for one of my websites, to bypass the popup blocker in Chrome.

Let us say we have the following HTML button:

```html
<button id="clickMe">Click Me!</button>
```

Now when the user clicks on the button, the first thing you should do is open an empty new window. After the [Fetch](https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-fetch-api) request is finished, update the actual window URL. If the request fails, simply close the window:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#clickMe');

// add click event listener
button.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // open an empty window
    const tab = window.open('about:blank');

    // make an API call
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {

            // TODO: do something with JSON response

            // update the actual URL
            tab.location = 'https://attacomsian.com';
            tab.focus();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // close the empty window
            tab.close();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case the `window.open` was launched inside a `promise` in angular, which turned the popup blocker on, my solution was:

```
$scope.gotClick = function(){

  var myNewTab = browserService.openNewTab();
  someService.getUrl().then(
    function(res){
      browserService. updateTabLocation(res.url, myNewTab);
    }
  );
};
```

browserService:

```
this.openNewTab = function(){
  var newTabWindow = $window.open();
  return newTabWindow;
}

this.updateTabLocation = function(tabLocation, tab) {
  if(!tabLocation){
    tab.close();
  }
  tab.location.href = tabLocation;
}
```

this is how you can open a new tab using the `promise` response and not invoking the popup blocker.

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution did not work for me, but I based on it and used named window.

```
internalCounter++;
var tabbedWin = window.open('','windowName_'+internalCounter);
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: false,
        indexValue:internalCounter,
        success: function(){
            var w= window.open(url, 'windowName_'+this.indexValue);                
            w.focus();
        }
})
```

Comment: referencing the solution from gabe

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

1. Redirect to the same page with download url added as parameter:

```js
window.location.href = window.location.protocol + '//' +
                    window.location.host + window.location.pathname +
                    "?download=" + encodeURIComponent(urlToDownload)
```

2. Detect this parameter on page initialization and redirect to download:

```js
function param(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (!results) { return 0; }
    return results[1] || 0;
}

var downloadParam = param('download');
if (downloadParam) {
    window.location = decodeURIComponent(downloadParam);
}
```