# preview on another tab after inserting data into database

Tags: javascript

After inserting data into database I want just a preview of the new post - in another tab.

```
$('#btnpreview').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(){
        window.open('../view.php?t=preview&id=1', '_blank');
        }
    });
});
```

On localhost there is no problem but on remote server the link is blocked by Chrome Pop Up Blocker.

How to solve this?

I see there is a simmilar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602964/how-do-i-prevent-google-chrome-from-blocking-my-popup/4603026#4603026) and accepted answer but just the answer not the practical solution. What should I really do following each of given option?

Comment: see this answer to solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/4603026/3511012

Comment: I see there is the accepted answer but just the answer not the practical solution. What should I really do following each of given option?