# Axios disconnecting what happens next from user's action when called after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, axios

I have the following code which basically does the following:

> When the user clicks the button, an encoded text is sent to an `API` which takes care to decode it. Then the decoded text is set as a query on a Google link which is opened on a new tab.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Reference:
// https://base62.io/
let message_encoded = 'T8dgcjRGkZ3aysdN'; // base62('Hello World!'')
let way = 1;

$(function () {
  $('.button_test').click(async function() {
    let url_api = 'https://api.base62.io/decode';
    let response;
    switch (way) {
        case 1: /* this works */
            response = await jQuerySyncPost(url_api, { data: message_encoded });
            break;
        case 2: /* this DOES NOT work */
            response = await fetchSyncPost(url_api, { data: message_encoded });
            break;
        case 3: /* this DOES NOT work */
            response = await axios.post(url_api, { data: message_encoded });
            break;
    }
    alert('Next, let\'s look on Google for: "' + response.data.decoded + '"');
    let message_decoded = response.data.decoded;
    let url_google = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+encodeURIComponent(message_decoded);
    openNewTab(url_google);
  });
});
function jQuerySyncPost(url, params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: params,
      async: false,
      success: function (response) {
        response = {
          data: response
        };
        resolve(response);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        reject({
          jqXHR: jqXHR,
          textStatus: textStatus,
          errorThrown: errorThrown
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
function fetchSyncPost(url, params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let config = {
        headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(params),
      method: 'POST',
    };
    fetch(url, config)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        let result = {
          data: response,
        };
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
}
function openNewTab(url) {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="button_test">Click Here</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.button_test {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

The code above is working fine with the `jQuery` Ajax call (through custom function):

```
let response = await syncPost(url_api, { data: message_encoded });
```

But, in the other hand, if I use `axios`, then I get a `popup blocked` alert on the browser which prevents the new tab to get opened:

```
let response = await axios.post(url_api, { data: message_encoded });
```

Here you have the `JSFiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/otyzadju
where `{ way=1 }` works, but `{ way=2, way=3 }` don't.

On both cases the call to the `API` via Ajax is done synchronously but the problem is that it seems that `axios` is disconnecting what happens next from user's action when called after clicking a button.

Any idea on how to make this work with `axios`?

If possible, please, provide your solution on a forked `JSFiddle` link.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit similar - I hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602964/how-do-i-prevent-google-chrome-from-blocking-my-popup

Comment: @Sparlarva that's not similar. They don't use `axios`. My goal is to use `Axios`.

Comment: Okay but you haven't posted a problem using an axios solution.

Comment: yes I did, just uncomment the line: `await axios.post` and comment the line: `await syncPost`

Comment: Have you looked in the development console to see what the error is on the browser? I can also see that there are no headers added when you are using axios?

Comment: there is no error on the console log. I also tried with `window.fetch` API but it didn't work either. Please, check the `JSFiddle` example above with: `way=2`. Just in case, I copy paste the link here too: https://jsfiddle.net/73bufk4r

Comment: I basically changed to window.open but i realise that your opennewtab function also includes some other attributes, please let me know if you need any.

Comment: I updated the test code to: https://jsfiddle.net/otyzadju but keep getting the popup blocker with: `{ way=2, way=3 }`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the answer to window.open so it will work with axios.post - it also works with fetch. If you didn't use this originally for a certain reason then please let me know and I can try and update the answer.

```
function openNewTab(url) {
      window.open(url, '_blank')

}
```

This is a JSfiddle fork with it set to option 2 and the opennewtab function altered.

https://jsfiddle.net/xuywfqzn/

Comment: Unfortunatelly I keep getting the popup blocker with: `{ way=2, way=3 }`. I ended up using the other code for `openNewTab(...)` I think because I tried wrong parameters with `window.open(...)` initially. I updated it's code, thanks for that. Beside that, I keep having the issue with the popup blocker. Do you say you don't get the popup blocker?, maybe you disabled it on the browser config? I tried with both: `Chrome` and `Firefox` and on both browsers I get the popup blocker with ways: 2 and 3. Here is my code updated: https://jsfiddle.net/otyzadju Thanks!

Comment: My pop up definitely disappeared even with it enabled i checked but let me look again, give me a little time im just about to have my birthday cake (dont worry its my birthday in 4 days - just at my parents)