# How to Fix Window Open Function

Tags: javascript

i have code

```
aff_url = $(this).attr('data-aff-url'); 
current_url = $(this).attr('href'); 
window.open( aff_url, '_self'); 
window.open( current_url, '_blank');
```

but the window open function is not working chrome the popup blocker is blocking window open anyone can help me to make it work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent Google Chrome from blocking my popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602964/how-do-i-prevent-google-chrome-from-blocking-my-popup)

Comment: This is a browser security feature. It is not recommended to bypass this.

Comment: If you still want to do that then try to add the link in the HTML and trigger click on it.

Comment: will this work ? onclick='window.open(this.href);return false;'