# want to bypass a popup on page load containing only webaddress

Tags: javascript, html

in my one website i want a pop up appear on page load and this pop up must not be block by pop up blocker

I have tried location.href

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function aaa()
{
var href= "http://digiskills.pk";

popup = window.open('http://digiskills.pk', 'width=400 height=400');


 if (popup === null || typeof popup === "undefined")
  {
   location.href = href;

  } 
 else 
  {
   popup.focus();

  }
}



</script>
</head>
<body onload=aaa()>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code only by pass but not open the URL in pop up

Comment: I think you misunderstand the point of a popup blocker... its to block... pop ups... There isn't a simple easy way to bypass pop-up blockers. If you really must shove something in the users face, make an absolutely positioned div in the middle of the screen and only show it when you want to..

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: Location href is for the page you are on, not the popup. maybe look into modals rather than a popup.

Answer (score 0):

Onload popups will almost always be blocked by modern browsers. These blockers are *extremely* hard to circumvent and doing so probably shouldn't be your goal in the first place. If you absolutely must have a popup, you could open one after a user takes an action. Popup blockers will, for the most part, not block popups that are opened as a direct result of user action, such a click or keystroke.

See [How do I prevent Google Chrome from blocking my popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602964/how-do-i-prevent-google-chrome-from-blocking-my-popup)

You will also need to add a window name as the second argument, otherwise the width and height you passed will be interpreted as the name for the new window.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Popup Test</title>
  <script>
    // Won't work in Stackoverflow due to security precautions, copy to a html file to test it out
    function pop() {
      let popup = window.open('http://digiskills.pk', 'Digiskills', 'width=400,height=400');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="pop()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```