# how to capture "allow popups and redirects" event from popups blocked by google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Do we receive any callback event/function when user clicks allow in popups block button in google chrome?

[image]

Comment: Check this thread, could solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602964/how-do-i-prevent-google-chrome-from-blocking-my-popup

Answer (score 1):

To detect if a browser is blocking a popup with JavaScript, we can check the closed property of the window.

You can call `window.open` to open the url. Then we check if the window **object closed property** is `true` or `undefined` or if the window object is `false`.

If any of these are true, then the window is blocked from opening.

Comment: I was asking how I can get some event when user clicks on "always allow popups" and done.

Comment: Sorry @Always_a_learner , I did not understand your question correctly. The only thing I can think of is to try it with [monitorEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15923770/7306365)