# window.open popup getting blocked during click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

What I ultimately need to do is run an `$.ajax()` call and then after that is run, open a new window.

A use clicks on a "Preview" button that saves their current form then opens a new window that shows a preview of the item with the data that was just saved.

But as-is, the `window.open` function gets blocked by popup blockers.

Here's the basic parts of my code:

HTML:

```
<a href="/surveys/185/preview" class="preview" target="_blank">Preview</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.preview').live('click', function(event){
  save_survey($(this).attr('href'));
  event.preventDefault();
});

function save_survey(url) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: form_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(data) {
      window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I ran into this problem recently and found this work-around:

1) call `window.open` just before calling `$.ajax` and save window reference:

```
var newWindow = window.open(...);
```

2) on callback set `location` property of the saved window reference:

```
newWindow.location = url;
```

Maybe it will help you too.

Comment: This is incredibly clever. And I thought there was no hope.

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work anymore.  Can someone confirm that this isn't possible?

Comment: @IgorDymov This seems to work with major browser. Could you elaborate why this works.

Comment: For those who find that this isn't working, I noticed that window.open can return null if not triggered by a user-initiated event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18401663/1415038.

Comment: What if I don’t have the url before Ajax response?

Answer (score 15):

Popup blockers usually works blocking every popup shown not triggered by a direct user action, like clicking on a button or a link.

If you use a ajax request on your click event, the request is fired asyncronous from the click event, that's why by the time the ajax request has done its job and you get your event with the response from the request you have lost your chance to trigger a window.open withouth the popup blocker getting in the way, the original click event it's long dead by that time.

Answer (score 3):

According this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-pop-up-blockers), it looks like you would have to open your window in direct response to the click (to avoid getting hit by the popup blockers) rather than waiting until the AJAX call completes to open the new window.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my case by making the Ajax call synchronous. E.g. (with jQuery):

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      url: ...,
      data: ...,
      success: function(results){
          if(results.valid){
              window.open(...);
          }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newWin = window.open(`${BASE_URL}`, 'expampleName')
if (newWin) {
  newWin.onload = () => {
    const currentOpenWindow = newWin
    const href = newWin.location.href
  }
}
```

Comment: could you explain, how this answers the question?

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.