# Window.open blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I found another thread on stackoverflow: [[window.open popup getting blocked during click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628949/window-open-popup-getting-blocked-during-click-event)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628949/window-open-popup-getting-blocked-during-click-event). And the top answer seems to solve the problem. But I don't know a lot of JavaScript.

Can you help rewrite the code according the answer:

1) Call `window.open` just before calling `$.ajax` and save window reference:

```
var newWindow = window.open(...);
```

2) On callback set location property of the saved window reference:

```
newWindow.location = url;
```

Maybe it's already in an explicit way. But I don't have any idea how to rewrite the code.

Comment: You should post the code you tried first and then you will find many people willing to help you refactor it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, keeping in mind the context of the question you linked to, it would be something like this:

```
var newUrl = 'http://example.com';
var newWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: form_url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: form_data,
  success: function(data) {
    newWindow.location = newUrl;
  }
});
```

Of course, you'd have to modify the `$.ajax` call (url and data, specifically)  to match your requirements.