# window.open returns null and fails in inline script but works from console

Tags: javascript, window.open

I'm using Smarty template system. One of its features is posibility to output script that generates debug information for every page. Here you can see an example of generated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

setTimeout(function() {  //Attempt to fix the issue with timeout
    var _smarty_console = window.open("about:blank","md5hash","width=680,height=600,resizable,scrollbars=yes");
    console.log(_smarty_console);  //Trying to log it
    if(_smarty_console!=null) {
      _smarty_console.document.write("<!DOCTY... lots of HTML ...<\/html>\n");
      _smarty_console.document.close();
    }
}, 5000);
//]]> 
</script>
```

The problem is, that the `window.open` functions always returns `null`. I tried to delay it with `setTimeout` but nothing changed. When I copy the code and run it in Firebug console, it works properly. There are no other scripts on page. The page uses strict XHTML. The script is right before `</body>`.

Comment: This is maybe a stupid question, but can you actually see the pop-up? If you can't, switch off the pop-up blocker in your browser...

Comment: `setTimeout(function () {
  window.open(url);
}, 1000)` worked for me

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is blocked by the browser. `window.open` is only not being blocked, when it is invoked by user action, for example in a click event, emitted by a native browser event. Also javaScript emitted events are being blocked, just like delayed setTimeout callbacks.

```
<a id="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Example (with jQuery for simplicity)

$("a#link").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var url = this.href;

  // this will not be blocked
  var w0 = window.open(url);
  console.log("w0: " + !!w0); // w0: true

  window.setTimeout(function () {
    // this will be blocked
    var w1 = window.open(url);
    console.log("w1: " + !!w1); // w1: false
  }, 5000);
});

</script>
```

Watch the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ny7W/). I also tried it with the `keypress` event, but no luck.

`window.open` returns a valid reference to the new (or an existing named) window, or `null` when it failed to create a new window.

Comment: I thought it would be something browser related. But since no "Popup was blocked." message appeared, I was confused. Could you give me an advice how to get it to work? I want it to work without changing the browser settings of course.

Comment: no way. only through a click event, just like the example in my post (update)

Comment: Not even a key event worked (CTRL+j). under such circumstances, I'll have to add an exception for my page.

Answer (score -6):

Try the next command after window.open with timeout, for example:

```
var myWindow = window.open('foo','_blank','menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, top=10, width=800,height=600');

setTimeout( myWindow.onload=function(){this.document.body.innerHTML+='bar';}, 2000 );
```

Comment: How should that help? How is it related to the question? Can you explain more?

Comment: What's the meaning of this code related to the question?