# multiple javascript window.open calls fail in chrome and IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, window.open

A set of multiple window.open() calls, as described at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open6, for example ...

```
    w1=window.open("http://www.google.com/");
    w2=window.open("http://www.w3schools.com/");
```

... works as expected in FireFox, but opens just one new tab in Chrome 36 and IE 11.

Anybody know a way to make this work in Chrome & IE?

Comment: Your 2nd popup is being blocked by the built-in popup blocker.  Why do you need to open multiple popups at the same time?

Comment: I ran into the same issue myself. I don't think the "why" is particularly important, I needed to have a single button open up two pages in a new tab or window. Doing two consecutive `window.open()` calls in Chrome only opens the first one and blocks the second. Works fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to pop up two stand-alone windows.  The second window would REPLACE the first window's link.  I found the answer was to give the windows different names. example: "test1" and "test2"

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open("http://www.google.com", "test1",  "resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,width=260,height=225");
window.open("http://www.google.com", "test2", "resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,width=260,height=225");
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: For me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401331/window-open-returns-null-and-fails-in-inline-script-but-works-from-console solved the issue as it turned out to be Chrome security blocking the pop-up.