# Why is win undefined?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this in `javascript` to chat. Now I can call `openChat` with clicking a `button` and that works. But if I call it from `onmessage`-event, I get the

> error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of
>   undefined

I'm new to javascript and I don't know, why I get this error?. Can somebody maybe help me? 
Thanks:)

Thats the code:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        busy: false,
        roomId: 'POWebinar',
        joinedRoom: false,
        chatWirCB: false,
        chatKundenCB: false,
        microphoneWirCB: false,
        microphoneKundenCB: false,
        user: 'Benutzer',
    },
    methods: {
    openChat: function () {
        console.log("in fkt openChat");
        win = window.open('', 'myconsole',
            'scrollbars=1, width=450,height=500'
            + ',menubar=1'
            + ',toolbar=1'
            +', location=1'
            + ',resizable=1')
        win.document.writeln("<head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no'></head><body style='background-color:#ecf0f1'></body>");
        chat = document.getElementById("chatHtml").innerHTML;
        win.document.write(chat);
        win.document.title = "PatOrg - Live Chat";
        win.document.getElementById('input-text-chat').onkeyup = function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
            // removing trailing/leading whitespace
            this.value = this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

            var a = new Date();
            var b = a.getHours(); var c = a.getMinutes(); var d = a.getSeconds();
            if (b < 10) { b = '0' + b; }
            if (c < 10) { c = '0' + c; }
            if (d < 10) { d = '0' + d; }
            var time = b + ':' + c + ':' + d;

            if (!this.value.length) return
            console.log(this.value);

            connection.send('<div id="chatSend" class="chat-OutputGET bubbleGET"> <font color="white">' + username + '(' + time + '): ' + this.value + '</font></div>');
            console.log(username);
            console.log('User (' + time + '): ' + this.value);
            appendDIV('<div id="chatGet" class="chat-OutputSEND bubble"> <font color="white"> Ich (' + time + '): ' + this.value + '</font></div>');

            this.value = '';

        };
        var chatContainer = win.document.getElementById('chat-output');
        function appendDIV(event) {
            if (event == "turnMicroOff" || event.data == "turnMicroOff" || event == "turnMicroOn" || event.data == "turnMicroOn" || event == "turnChatOn" || event.data == "turnChatOn" || event == "turnChatOff" || event.data == "turnChatOff") {
                if (event == "turnMicroOff" || event.data == "turnMicroOff") {
                    console.log("audioID: " + audioID);
                    console.log("audioID: " + audioID);
                    for (i = 0; i < audioID.length; i++) {
                        connection.streamEvents[audioID[i]].stream.mute('audio');
                    }
                }
                else if (event == "turnMicroOn" || event.data == "turnMicroOn") {
                    console.log("audioID: " + audioID);
                    console.log("audioID: " + audioID);
                    for (i = 0; i < audioID.length; i++) {
                        connection.streamEvents[audioID[i]].stream.unmute('audio');
                    }
                }
                else if (event == "turnChatOn" || event.data == "turnChatOn") {
                    document.getElementById("btnChatOpen").style.visibility = "visible";
                }
                else if (event == "turnChatOff" || event.data == "turnChatOff") {
                    document.getElementById("btnChatOpen").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }

            }
            else {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = event.data || event;
                chatContainer.appendChild(div);
                div.tabIndex = 0;
                div.focus();
                win.document.getElementById('input-text-chat').focus();
                emojify.run(win.document.getElementById('chat-output'));
            }
        }
        connection.onmessage = appendDIV;
    }
}
```

})

```
connection.onmessage = function (event) {
console.log(event.data);
if (event == "turnMicroOff" || event.data == "turnMicroOff") {
    for (i = 0; i < audioID.length; i++) {
        console.log("audioID: " + audioID[i]);
        connection.streamEvents[audioID[i]].stream.mute('audio');
    }

}
else if (event == "turnMicroOn" || event.data == "turnMicroOn") {
    app.openChat();
    for (i = 0; i < audioID.length; i++) {
        console.log("audioID: " + audioID[i]);
        connection.streamEvents[audioID[i]].stream.unmute('audio');
    }
}
else if (event == "turnChatOn" || event.data == "turnChatOn") {
    document.getElementById("btnChatOpen").style.visibility = "visible";
}
else if (event == "turnChatOff" || event.data == "turnChatOff") {
    document.getElementById("btnChatOpen").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

}

Comment: Add blocker must have blocked that page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.open returns null and fails in inline script but works from console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401331/window-open-returns-null-and-fails-in-inline-script-but-works-from-console)

Comment: Doesn't work with disabled add-blocker too.

Comment: Does the new tab opens?

Comment: Oh ok, there is no solution :( Does somebody know another way to realize it? I want that the chat window opens or the icon in the taskleiste flashes when someone gets a message and the window is not open already.

Comment: @Rajesh No nothing happens

Comment: You can try to create a dummy anchor tag on your current window and trigger its click. This will open page, but then you will not have reference of `window` to manipulate. You will have to add manipulation code to start-up script somehow.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Maybe with an example, as i said i'm really new to javascript.