# Merge functions to run serveral lines of JS code on browser Console

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to batch download PDF files on a single page like this:

http://procweb.jfrj.jus.br/portal/consulta/resinfopecas2.asp?CodDoc=76359308&CodUsuWeb=

I need to click every item to open a page that redirects me to a PDF file. That's what the function "MostraPeca" does.

If I run this function on Chrome console it also works:

```
MostraPeca('75959255','406','','14/03/2017 16:35:21','3744','3','1','930853');
```

And I already have a list like this:

```
MostraPeca('75959255','406','','14/03/2017 16:35:21','3744','3','1','930853');
MostraPeca('75959255','287','','31/01/2017 14:24:48','3358','1','1','513367');
MostraPeca('75959255','605','','06/04/2017 13:47:49','4061','1','1','929011');
MostraPeca('75959255','780','','12/05/2017 16:20:56','4706','1','1','350899');
MostraPeca('75959255','759','','08/05/2017 16:05:41','4657','13','2','825754');
MostraPeca('75959255','142','','19/12/2016 15:53:09','1884','1','1','589882');
```

But when I paste it on console just the first line runs. I would like run all lines at the same time. How it would be posible?

EDIT:

I've checked in the website source code and the functions looks like this:

```
    function MostraPeca( P1, P2, P3, DTI, NPI, NPT, TI, NV) {
        var newWindow;
        var left = (screen.width - 600) / 2;
        var top = (screen.height - 450) / 2;
        if (left < 0) {left = 1;}
        if (top < 0) {top = 1;}
        var props = 'resizable=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,width=600,height=450'+',top='+top+',left='+left;
        newWindow = window.open('mostraarquivo.asp?P1='+P1+'&P2='+P2+'&P3='+P3+'&DTI='+DTI+'&NPI='+NPI+'&NPT='+NPT+'&TI='+TI+'&NV='+NV, 'pdf'+NPI , props);
    }
```

Comment: this *sounds like* an issue with the function itself.  However, without seeing the contents of the function, it's impossible to know for sure.  This is a question that isn't answerable without code.

Comment: thanks Claies, i've pasted the code from that function above. is it enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its chrome trying to protect you against malicious websites. You will notice that chrome brings up an alarm with a message like 
[image]

If you select "Always allow pop-ups from (your url)" then these functions will not be blocked.
you can read more information here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401331/window-open-returns-null-and-fails-in-inline-script-but-works-from-console)