# Open a view in new tab from javascript when controller returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to open a new tab after the controller success, the controller returns a View

This is my approach but it doesn't work:

```
function modify(){

  var1= someDataFromDOM;
  var2= anotherDataFromDOM;

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("ModifyObject", "ControllerName")',
    data: {id: var1, status: var2},
    success: function (data){
       var newTab = window.open("", "_blank", "",  true);
       newTab.document.body.innerHTML = data;
    }
  });
}
```

On the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ModifyObject(int id, string status)
{
   ViewModelA model = new ViewModelA();
   model = bd.GetModelA(id, status);
   return View("ModifyObject", model);
}
```

**The controller returns the view correctly but the newTab variable has null value**

Any help will be welcome

Comment: Is your controller name `ControllerController`?

Comment: No, @ibubi the name it's only an example but I just edited it.

Comment: why don't you just open `@Url.Action("ModifyObject", "ControllerName")` in a new tab? The ajax is adding no benefit here, it's just ,making it more complicated

Comment: And how can I do it that from js @Liam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is with the javascript `window.open()`. This function is blocked by browsers except user events. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822711/jquery-window-open-in-ajax-success-being-blocked) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401331/window-open-returns-null-and-fails-in-inline-script-but-works-from-console)

Below is a workaround for your purposes, I have tested;

```
<input type="button" hidden="hidden" id="hack" />

$(function () {

    var var2 = "test";
    var var1 = 1;
    var htmlData;
    var win;

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("ModifyObject", "Controller")',
        data: { id: var1, status: var2 },
        success: function (data) {
            htmlData = data;
            $("#hack").trigger("click");
        }
    });

    $("#hack").on("click", function () {
        win = window.open("", "_blank");
        win.document.body.innerHTML = htmlData;

    });
});
```

However, opening a new tab like this may not be a good approach. 
It is not apperant what your `modify()` does, but I would not use ajax to open a new window, I would try to replace it with the below instead, please check [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/)

```
Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ModifyObject", "ControllerName", new { Id = "param1", Status = "param2" }, new { target = "_blank" });
```

**Update**

Try this as per your comment;

```
function modify()
{
    var grid = $("#datagrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var row = grid.getSelectedRow(); 

    var win = window.open("","_blank")
    var var1 = row.fieldID;
    var var2 = row.fieldStatus;
    var url = '@Url.Action("ModifyObject", "ControllerName")' + '?id=' + var1 + '&status=' + var2;
    win.location = url;
}
```

Comment: I could use it for sure. If this is not the best way to do it, what would you do?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: that would be perfect if I didn't need two parameters from the DOM to pass to the controller, this is the reason for make the call in js

Comment: It is simple, I forgot to add that, now it is updated

Comment: Thanks for the help @ibubi but don't know how to pass the parameters at client side... See the jsfiddle (pseudocode) -> [link](https://jsfiddle.net/d7ky4jae/)

Comment: Thanks @ibubi perfect for me!