# Why is window.open() returning null in unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dart, flutter-web

I'm writing a unit test for a method that launches a browser window when a user clicks a button.

The test fails because `null` is returned.

When running the test no browser window is opened.

When using the app it works as expected.

I've seen a lot of the other SO questions regarding window.open() returning null or otherwise not doing what the OP wanted, but these all have to do with getting the browser to do specific things. The code I'm testing does what I want it to do when used in the web app, but I'm not able to write a passing unit test for it. This unit test is a step along the way to fixing a problem that occurs in the step after this method runs, which is why I want to understand why this test isn't passing.

The top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401331/window-open-returns-null-and-fails-in-inline-script-but-works-from-console) lead me to think that the browser might be blocking a new window because the request is coming from outside the browser, which would result in a `null` return. I disabled popup blocking in Chrome just in case.

This is main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';
import 'dart:html' as html;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Minimal, Reproducible Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PrintReports extends StatelessWidget {

  const PrintReports({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text(
            "Print A Form . . ."
          ),
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () => { 
            // generate form . . .
            // request submission . . .
            // launch browser window . . .
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future launchURL(String download_url) 
  async {
    try {
      await html.window.open(download_url, "Get_Submission");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

This is test.dart:

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter_tests/main.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main(){
  test("_launchURL launches browser at correct URL", () async {
    // Arrange: setup the test
    PrintReports printReports = PrintReports();

    // Act
    WindowBase window = await printReports.launchURL("https://someurl.com/download");

    // Assert
    expect(window, WindowBase);
  });
}
```

To run the test I'm using this terminal command: `pub run test test/print_reports_card_test.dart -p chrome`.

The current test results are:

```
00:14 +2 -1: _launchURL launches browser at correct URL [E]                                                                                      
  Expected: Type:<WindowBase>
    Actual: <null>

[ . . . I can post this redacted output if you think it might be relevant . . . ]

00:14 +2 -1: Some tests failed.
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to work with `xvfb`, specifically `xvfb-run`. I do have X11 installed and `where xvfb` returns `/opt/X11/bin/xvfb`, but I don't have `xvfb-run` available; `xvfb-run -a pub run test test/print_reports_card_test.dart -p chrome` returns `zsh: command not found: xvfb-run`.

Comment: This is the conversation that lead me to look into `xvfb` and `xvfb-run`: https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/563. If I understand this correctly, the issue might be that the test can't open a browser because I'm running this code outside of a browser. A fix might be to run a headless browser, which is what I'm trying to figure out how to do. I still haven't found a way to get/install `xvfb-run`.

Comment: You can get a copy of xvfb-run from: https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/plain/trunk/xvfb-run?h=packages/xorg-server

It is just a script to make use of xvfb in a more nice way.

Comment: @julemand101, Thank you. I'll check that out.