# VueJS and axios: can't use url in axios response to open in a new window

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have the followwing two methods in an `vuejs` component:

```
    openLender: function(setUrl) {
        const win = window.open(setUrl, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    },
    getLender: function(setEnt, setEx, setRev, setCred, setDur, checkWishes, lender) {
        const vm = this;
        const request = 'lender_click';
        const setWishes = vm.arrayToString(checkWishes);
        axios({
            method:'get',
            url:'/api',
            params: {
                request: request,
                setent: setEnt,
                setex: setEx,
                setrev: setRev,
                setcred: setCred,
                setdur: setDur,
                setwishes: setWishes,
                setlender: lender
            },
            responseType:'json'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            const url = response.data;
            vm.openLender(url[0].response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    }
```

The problem is that i get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null`

When I `console.log(url[0].response)` the response, it does show me the url that I got from the `axios` request, but when I use the `openLender()` method it gives me this error.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

I used @IgorDymov his solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628949/window-open-popup-getting-blocked-during-click-event) post to work-around this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.open` method is always blocked by browser if it's not caused directly by a `click` event. Turn popup blocking off and it will work.

You may open the url in the same window or provide user a link to the new page though.