# javascript- window.open in safari and chrome in body?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom

I am adding the following javascript at runtime to open a new browser window. I know window.open is available in javascript. But it doesn't work for safari and chrome. Is there any other trick or hooking technique to achieve this.

```
     string script= "window.open('http://www.w3schools.com','_blank','toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=no,status=1,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,copyhistory=yes,left=20,top=20,width=600,height=550');";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newWindowScript",  script, true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the popup blocker in the browser. You can use Ajax Modal Popup window instead of Window.Open

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Another option is Jquery popup
http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/

if you still need to use Window.Open then please refer this

[Bypass popup blocker on window.open when JQuery event.preventDefault() is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set)

Comment: I need to open full fledged web page not a popup.

Comment: That is what I don't want to do. Because when we say to do so then clients shows their frustration.

Comment: No. I want to see if it is caused by Popup blocker or not. So just say the result after disabling the popup blocker, then we can work on that.

Comment: It is difficult to avoid popup blocker unless it is opened in a user event. Refer this link for alternative.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open()` most certainly works in Safari and Chrome, I used it today! The demos on the w3Schools site work in Chrome

Try moving the code into a standard in-page `<script>` block (obviously with the .net stuff removed) to test and see if you get any errors in the console.

It could be that one of the features you are passing as the 3rd argument to `.open()` is breaking things (like the copyhistory feature - I never saw that before, and it isn't listed in the available options on the w3Schools site)? I have noticed that Chrome tends to ignore the width and open it to whatever size it wants to...

Comment: I tested without other parameters except the width and hight, but still no luck.