# Is there any way to execute gapi.client.request synchronously?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

jQuery allows to send http request as synchronous (async:false setting), this is particularly useful when [bypassing popup blocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set).

Is there any way to do this when using Google's javascript client library [Gapi](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#option-2-use-gapiclientrequest) ?

Answer (score 0):

No. As I see, there is no such option in [gapi.client.request](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequestargs) documentation.