# window.open auto new tab not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

Javascript `window.open()` auto new tab not working in Google-Chrome and bypass all browser open new tab.

** auto new tab without click button and click link **

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          window.open("http://www.google.co.th");
      </script>';
```

** Run for IE  "pass"

** Run for Firefox  "pass"

** Run for Chrome "fail"

Comment: *new window popup without click* - that'll be blocked by the popup blocker.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
window.open('http://www.google.co.th','','height=200,width=300');
```

Chrome will block popup windows on page, until you give him access.