# Insert iframe/object in popup issue

Tags: iframe, popup

Good evening,

I have an issue with inserting an iframe or object in a popup created like that:

```
//Version 1
function fShowPop()
{   
    var oPopup = window.createPopup();

    oPopup.document.body.innerHTML = '<iframe id="ifrmPop" src="<myLink>"></iframe>';

    oPopup.show(15, 150,200, 200, document.body);
}

//Version 2
function fShowPop()
{   
    var oPopup = window.createPopup();

    oPopup.document.body.innerHTML = '<object  data="<myLink>" type="text/html"></object>';

    oPopup.show(15, 150,200, 200, document.body);
}
```

So the result is a blank square...
And the page source is not affected.

```
<html><body></body></html>
```

If I use document.write the source is affected but it stay blank.

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 Possible Problems:

- The `window.createPopup()` method is no longer supported. It used to be an Internet-Explorer-only function, but now it's not supported in any browser at all.
- The `iframe` has no `width` or `height` attributes set, so it'll be zero size. However, modern browsers have a default iframe size of 300 pixels by 150 pixels.

Since the most likely reason is no browser support, check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html, which is an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your advises! Unfortunatetly window.open, is blocked by the browser..

Comment: Google Chrome is smart. In Chrome, it will allow window.open only if it's caused by user action. For example, you can click a button to open a pop-up, but the pop-up isn't allowed to open by itself. Firefox also has a similar implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately IE is the only browser supported. I must find a way to bypass the popup blocker... I tried to simulate a button click, but the browser is smarter than me! I can't use jquery and ajax, even the vanilla javascript version of ajax call... I'm very limited on my moves...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it:

```
//Version 3
function fShowPop()
{   
    var oPopup = window.createPopup();
    oPopup.document.body.innerHTML = '<a target="_blank" href="<mylink>"><img title="" src="../../pics/mypic.gif" border="0"></a>';
    oPopup.show(15, 150,200, 200, document.body);
}
```

There is a strange behavior with the popup, but at least it show well.

Thank you!

EDIT: finally it does not work...forget about it. Window.open seems the only way to achieve it...