# codepen.io - window.open is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this button that's supposed to open a random wikipedia page. In the codepen editor everything works fine, but when I open it full-page, the random button doens't work anymore and in the log it says 'window.open is disabled'.

Looking around I saw that it might be because I was calling the window.open inside an ajax call, which is asynchronous and therefore not allowed ([Bypass popup blocker on window.open when JQuery event.preventDefault() is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set)) so I collect the url in the ajax call and call the window.open(url) inside the jquery .click function, but again: it works in codepen editor but not in the full-page version.

So I tried a simpler version, which still doesn't work:

```
 $('#random').click(function() {
  window.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki")
})
```

I don't think it's a browser misconfiguration, because it wouldn't work in the editor either, and that's not the case. Tried with both chrome and FF.

Any idea or workaround?

Comment: Do you have any other JS libraries/SDKs/whatever embedded? Live example?

Comment: I only added bootstrap and jquery  Here the full-page http://codepen.io/ni-kun/full/RPewRV/

Comment: if codepen, could you post the link here?

Comment: Then it’s probably codepen overwriting the `window.open` method, with one that just logs the message to console.

Comment: So I should assume there's nothing wrong with my code? But shouldn't the compiler do the same job in both the editor and in the full page view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with your code; it gives me `window.open is disabled` as well.

CodePen disables `window.open` so your best bet would be to experiment locally.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at it @towerofnix. It's really weird there isn't any note or mention about this around though, codepen it's widely used and I'd say window.open it's a pretty standard operation. Oh well, mystery solved anyway.

Comment: Yep, hopefully they make it so that it's more clear. At least change the message from `window.open is disabled` to `CodePen disables window.open`, you'd think?