# I want to open a new window on my current window using JS

Tags: javascript

I am using the  code shown in the images below. I have tried many ways like closing login window, before opening a new one. I have also tried many ways like `window.open("index.HTML", '_self', false)` and `window.location.replace("index.HTML")` but they are not working at all:

[image: HTML code]

[image: JS Code]

Comment: What happens when you try `window.open("index.html", '_self', false)`? Do you get a new window open?

Comment: it refreshing the same "Login" window and not opening "index.html"

Comment: And what if you did `window.open("https://www.google.com", '_self', false)`? Do you see the google site or Login page? If you see Google, you have a path relativity issue. You may wish to try `window.open("/index.html", '_self', false)` or `window.open("../index.html", '_self', false)`...

Comment: Or fully qualify it... `window.open("http://www.yourdomainname.com/index.html", '_self', false)`

Comment: Same results...not opening google.com

Comment: I really don't know how taking a screenshot, cropping it, uploading it and then copy paste that link is easier that just copy pasting the code.

Comment: Why screenshot? Copy the code, and paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `window.open("http://www.example.com", "_blank")`
Also check your pop-up blocker since it will most probably detect this as popup and block it.

If not then use a monkey patch which is create an html anchor tag with target="_blank". Hide it with CSS `visibility: hidden`, then invoke the click event using JS.

Read more about [popups and blocking in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set) If your `window.open` event was not triggered by a click then most probably it would be blocked.

Comment: He wants to open the window in the same tab  

To do this, one should not use `window.open(..., "_blank")` because this will open up the page in a new **blank** window

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, if I am not mistaken, is open a new webpage but using the same window (or tab)... To do this, you should modify the `window.location` property.

For example:

```
window.location = "new_page.html"
```

This will take you to `new_page.html`.

If your current location is: `/users/muhammad/index.html`
Then the page will take you to: `/users/muhammad/new_page.html`

### Leave a comment if you have any questions!

### =)

Comment: Exactly ! this is what i want..But the solution you provided is not working..i already tried this one..it's not taking me to new_page..but refreshing the old one.

Comment: Try doing this: CTRL + SHIFT + I (that is an uppercase i)

Comment: You will be prompted with a console. There type your command: `window.location = ...`, and leave a comment with the output of that command

Comment: well on typing  window.location = "index.html" on console . it's taking me to the page "index.html"

Comment: thats odd behavior... can you upload the code to dropbox, or google drive and comment a link so that I can further inspect the code

Comment: I got it...this happens only when i use Input of type="text"....but when i replace it with type ="email" ,it works fine ...i don't know why it's happening