# window.open not working as new tab is undefined

Tags: javascript

```
newtab = window.open('about:blank','_newtab' );
newtab.location.replace = ('http://www.yahoo.com/')
```

I need to open a new tab with a different domain. But the following error occured

```
instance_controller.js:184 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

Why this is happening? Please give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
newtab = window.open('about:blank', '_newtab');

newtab.location = ('http://www.yahoo.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because the `window.open` function has already executed and detatched itself from the parent scope. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Why not just use `window.open("http://www.yahoo.com/", "_blank");`?

Comment: browser will block the popup

Comment: Unfortunately/fortunately that's the browser standard

Answer (score 0):

```
newtab=window.open('http://www.yahoo.com/','_newtab' );
```

This will work but it will be blocked by popup blockers.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddledemo](https://jsfiddle.net/h7zot91g/)

```
var url = "http://www.example.com";
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy the issue is that you cannot programmatically interact with a page from another domain.  You do get a reference back to the window object - but because it is cross domain, you will get a very striped down set of functionality.

As the others have stated, you should just enter the url of the page that you want to load in your popup when you call the window.open function.

Comment: Then how i meet my requirement?I need to open new domain in a new tab but not without popup blocking@Rob Wilson

Comment: Ok, that's a different question.  I think, ultimately, you are at the mercy of the browser/popup blocker - if they don't want you opening windows, then there will probably be no consistent way to do this cross browser.  Here are a couple of links to that question, that may be of help (or may not ;)).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers

Comment: also, as suggested on those pages and the mozilla link, you may be able to change the location with:

    newtab.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com/'

but that also may not work across all browsers.....