# .net Response file - Open new tab

Tags: javascript, pdf, response

I have a handler (ashx)  and I would like to send a file to browser to the new tab.

I know that I can use the JavaScript (when I use the JS, the browser shows the message about blocking pop-up - I would like to avoid this message), but I would like to do this by Response from my handler. Is there any way?

I tried this, but this is open the PDF in the same window

```
  context.Response.Clear();
  context.Response.ClearHeaders();
  context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

I am calling the handler from Ajax:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/AcceptFormData",
                data: "{'funcParam': " + JSON.stringify(data) + "}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    window.location = "ashx/GetFile.ashx";
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try `window.open("ashx/GetFile.ashx");`

As a side note, it is a *user preference* whether to open a new tab versus a new window. See [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Edit: If your intent is to avoid the popup blocker, the general rule seems to be that the popup blocker will only allow `window.open()` during processing of a direct user event.  You have a few options:

- [Make your ajax call synchronous.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set)
- Present a modal or similar page element to the user during the ajax callback with a link or button to open the document and call `window.open()` during the click event.

Documentation: [MDN - Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: in this case the browser shows the pop-up blocker. I would like to avoid it.