# Browser identifying automatic anchor click as popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a purchase success page that has an anchor to show the invoice as a PDF such as

```
<a href="link" id="anchorId" target="targetId" style="display: none;">Click</a>
```

That purchase invoice has to be opened automatically, so I did like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#anchorId')[0].click();
    });
</script>
```

But browsers are not showing the new tab indicating this as a popup. I haven't used `window.open` so as not to have this kind of browser behaviour.

Is there anything doable to accomplish my use case?

Comment: Post complete code. `$('#anchorId')[0]` is invalid, since the `id` is unique.

Comment: Actually, that's the correct way to do it using `<a>`.

Comment: Addressing the anchor is not the problem, the full code isn't here.  There is no PDF and no loading function here.

Comment: @SteveHarris, I didn't understand your previous explanations. Actually that's the full code, I just omitted the real link. As I wrote in your answer, if I remove `display: none;` and click it, the invoice is displayed. Why do it automatically is wrong?

Comment: Fair enough, I see the "href".  The auto-click is considered a popup by definition.  Users can click without causing the blocking.

Comment: My advice is to open the popup from the previous page where they click "Confirm Order". It's easier and ad-block proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're described behavior is a popup by the browser's (and most folk's) definition so no, it is not likely you will find a workaround.  If you do it would be considered an "exploit".

Comment: If I remove `display: none;` and click it, the invoice is displayed. Why do it automatically is wrong?

Comment: Because that's what a popup is - An automatic new tab. It has to be triggered by a user event such as click/touch/mousedown etc.

Comment: This appears to be a possible duplicate question with your answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set