# open.window with a close button from parent window

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I am developing and app using Cordova(phonegap) which uses HTML and CSS and javascript and jquery, in one of the pages of my app I have a button which opens a URL for a question from the user.by using this code:

```
var URL="https://question.com/q1";
var ref=window.open(URL,'_parent','location=no,clearcache=yes,toolbar=no,titlebar=no');
```

now because I don't want to show the user the URL which they have been redirected I am removing the title bar which includes a close button.and now I don't have any button to close the page.I want to know if is it possible to add a close button to the parent page and show it when we open the new URL?

Comment: You have stored the opened window in a variable, just call .close() method when a button is clicked...

Comment: The problem is that how can I show the button(which is in the parent) when the new window is shown?

Comment: Have it previously created in the window with display: none and then show it: $('buttonId').show();

Comment: The new window completely covers the whole parent page.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button id="closeButton">close</button>
```

CSS:

```
#closeButton { 
  display:none; 
}
```

JS:

```
var URL="https://question.com/q1";
var openedWindow = window.open(URL,'_blank','location=no,clearcache=yes,toolbar=no,titlebar=no,width=600,height=600');
$('#closeButton').unbind().on('click', function(){
    openedWindow.close();
    $(this).hide();
});
$('#closeButton').show();
```

The second param "_blank" is what opens the new window instead of overlaying like you mentioned ("_parent"). You can set different initial width and height. Now with this solution, some browsers will flag this as a popup and will require permissions to open it (this is the more user-friendly way to do it instead of forcing opening a window) but if you want to by pass it, you can reference to this topic: [Bypass popup blocker on window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set)