# window.open("url","_self") works well on localhost url, but not when I put it on a server

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I have an angularJS frontend that I redirect to a third party payment gateway when a customer clicks on the Pay button.

I am currently using the following function to redirect to the payment gateway:

```
if(status.data.result == "true"){
var ref = window.open(url,'_self');
}
};
```

This code works well when I try it on localhost. But does not work when I put it on the ubuntu server.

Any ideas on why?

Regards,
Galeej

Comment: what error it throws?

Comment: May be your server blocking  the URL. check  it

Comment: @pro.mean no error.  Page just stays where it is.

Comment: @RameshRajendran nope.  Checked that the server is allowing the url.

Comment: because localhost is `whitelisted` in browser settings, your browser is blocking that popup see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `return false` after `var ref = window.open(url,'_self');` like

```
var ref = window.open(url,'_self');
return false;
```

`return false` will prevent from page submit and it may work this way to properly redirect on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

May be your **content security policy** is blocking this url to load. 
You can try using `_blank` instead of `_self` to see if that is the case. 
Also it would be better to use `$window`, because angular.

Also are you using the fully qualified URL ?

Comment: we are using a fully qualified url.  How do I check the content security policy?  will check with _blank and get back

Comment: `window.open(url,'_blank')` should open in a new tab.

Comment: Hey, this issue was fixed.  We used window.location = url and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for us was using window.location = url

Answer (score 0):

function(url:any){
window.open('#'+url,'_blank')
return false
}

Use click button in html side
<button (click)=function(/url) > Click 
should open in a new tab.