# Cannot read property 'document' of null when try to print html document

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angualr 2.

I am trying to print html div.

here is my code

```
<div id="print-section">
  // Html code
</div>
<button (click)="open()">print</button>

 print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
         </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

here is my open()

```
open(){
  //I called Api using service
   let scope=this;
   setTimeout(function() { scope.print(); }, 3000);
}
```

But i am getting this err

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null.

How can i fix this issue ?

Comment: `popupWin.documentElement.open` maybe?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Still i am getting same err?

Answer (score 2):

It is blocked by the browser. window.open is only not being blocked, when it is invoked by user action, for example in a click event, emitted by a native browser event.

Answer (score 1):

From MDN

> A Window object representing to the newly created window. If the
>   window couldn't be opened, the returned value is instead null. The
>   returned Window reference can be used to access properties and methods
>   of the new window as long as it complies with Same-origin policy
>   security requirements.

If it returned null, it means that the popup window has been blocked by the browser. Perhaps the action has not been initialized by user?

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution for your fix will be to rename **open()** function to something else and this will fix your error message.

*Copy/Paste in your chrome inspector console.*

```
function print() {
    let popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
         </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">test</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
function openOther(){
  //I called Api using service
   let scope=this;
   setTimeout(function() { scope.print(); }, 3000);
}
openOther()
```

In your case the **this** is the Window object, using the **open** name you override the native Window.open function.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I also tried to this.But it's not wrk

Comment: Your problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set
In your case if you remove setTimeout this will work