# change url of already opened popup

Tags: javascript, popup

Is it possible to change the url of the popup.

Assume I open a popup:

```
function pop1(){
    window.open('http://google.com','wind1');   
}
```

Can the url of the popup window 'wind1' be changed to say 'http://msn.com'. Something with location.href or any other solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
var w1 = window.open('http://www.canop.org','wind1');

w1.location.href='http://www.google.com';
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, as I was changing just the end of the url (parameters part), I used a little trick:
Loading a different url before using the new similar url.
I chose to use 'about:blank', but any website url could be used.

```
self.location = "about:blank";
self.location = desired_url;

//this code works fine both in Mozilla Firefox as in Chrome
```

Notice that just location = site; does the same as location.href = site.
I use location.href only to READ the current url.

Answer (score 1):

in the new popup window use this :

> $(document).ready(function(){
>   window.parent.location="http://www.google.com" })

Comment: He want's to change the content of the popup window, not the opener.

Comment: You told me the opposite. Will come handy when needed.