# Allow user to change URL in window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which opens a new window when a user clicks on a button:

```
$('.loginButton').click(function () {
    var strString = $("#medlineSearch").val()
    var strSearch = "http://google.com&query=";
    var url = strSearch + strString;
    alert(strSearch+strString);
    var windowName = $(this).attr('id');
    window.open(url, windowName, "height=750,width=1250,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,location=1");
    // custom handling here
    return false;
});
```

What I am looking to do is allow the user to enter something else in the address bar which seems to be read only.

Is there any way to change that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [change url of already opened popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774211/change-url-of-already-opened-popup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to change it, set the target to `_blank`.

This will prevent the new page to open as popup, but as new page.

```
window.open
( 'http://google.com'
, '_blank'
);
```

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwHGL/).

Comment: **Hits my head against the wall** Thanks :)

Comment: this does not work if a third parameter is provided (which it needs to be if the window also needs to be resized)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the url in popup window.

---

Read [change url of already opened popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774211/change-url-of-already-opened-popup)

---

Trick to do so

open console and type `location.href='http://link.com'`

Comment: The thing is, I want the address bar to be free text. I am thinking it is not possible to do that.

Comment: this actually changes the page... i'm trying take screenshots of a page not yet in production (release) but the URL is a staging URL which won't do for release documentation