# reloading new webpage content in the same opened tab through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, tabs

I have created two hyperlink in which when I click the hyperlink, it should open a new tab in the browser with the corresponding link webpage content, I have done that by using `window.open` feature,Its working fine, But the problem is that say when I click the hyperlink for the very first time it will open up a new tab, Again when I click the same or the second hyperlink it is opening another tab within the browser, instead If the current opened tab is still opened I need it be reloaded with that tab itself, If none of the tabs were opened then it should open a fresh new tab.

Is this can be done through JavaScript

My Code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/07hh3z2n/)**

**html**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openTab('http://stackoverflow.com')">StackOverflow</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openTab('https://github.com')">GitHub</a>
```

**script**

```
function openTab(link) {
    window.mypopup = window.open(link);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I changed my whole answer, since I saw there is a cleaner way you will prefer :

```
var w;

function openTab(link) {
if (typeof(w) === 'undefined')
    w = window.open(link);
else {
    w.location.href=link;
}

}
```

See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774211/change-url-of-already-opened-popup) where this problem has already been solved.

Cheers

Comment: cant we do anything like reloading with the new link,  instead of closing and opening

Comment: Changed my answer, take a look at it ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Tolokoban answer seems to be the clean way I guess

Comment: But my solution is not a good one: it works only with Firefox. Sorry. Maybe **bviale**'s solution can work with Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome seems to be unpermissive on this subject. My solution does not work on Chrome, neither does the "close() then open()" trick

Comment: window.open(link, "MyTab"); is working for my project for all browsers even IE9,10,11, may be in jsfiddle it is because of CORS

Answer (score 1):

You can use TARGET to use the same tab for different URLs.

http://jsfiddle.net/07hh3z2n/2/

This is the second argument of `window.open`.

```
window.open("http://en.wikipedia.org", "MyTab");
```

Comment: this is the clean Way I guess