# How to have a webpage cycle to a new one after a certain amount of time?

Tags: php, html, web, timer

This is a project i am tasked with at work.  I am to make a digital signage web page, and the idea is to have a raspberry pi go to a webpage and then go to another with different content.  The part i am unsure on is how do i get the webpage to send you to a new page say after 30 seconds. (the webpages are all hosted on an in house webserver)

example:  First Page - company splash page
          Second Page -  Employees coming up on another anniversary, maybe                    u                        upcoming birthdays.

and i just need a way to auto direct the computer to switch webpages from one to the next automatically.

I am using a raspberry pi, with the software Raspberry Digital Signage and it only allows for one webpage, so that's why i need this solution.

Any input would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: If you do not have control over pages that you want to swap between, the simplest solution would be to have a page that has javascript and opens other pages for you after a certain interval  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774211/change-url-of-already-opened-popup . Otherwise use Steve's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a simple HTML meta refresh redirect like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=http://example.com/" />
```

Adding this to your html (in the head) will let the page display, then automatically redirect to `http://example.com` after 30 seconds. No extras/JavaScript needed.

This is an "old-school" tag/trick and should be well supported by just about every browser.

**Note:** Setting it to 0 (`content="0,url=http://..."`) will initiate an immediate redirect.

Source: [CSS-Tricks (Meta Refresh)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/meta-refresh/)