# How to remove the URL of a page in an address bar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So everytime I click the href, there's a popup page which is `add_form.php` that will appear, and there's a form inside of it.

This is my code:

```
<a href="" onclick='return popup_link()'>Add</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
        function popup_link(){
        var url = 'add_form.php'; 
        window.open(url,'win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=1076,height=768,directories=no,location=no'); 
        }
</script>
```

I just want to know, how to remove the URL of the current page inside the address bar where in this is the output every time I click the `<href>` link.

```
http://127.0.0.1/no%20page%20reload/add_form.php
```

The above URL points to localhost. I don't want to see the URL on that popup page. So that everytime I print the current page, there's no URL included or displayed on the printed page.

Comment: You can't in modern day browsers

Comment: So there's no other options either?

Comment: Printing a page, that is a setting on the print set up to not include it or look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573603/removing-page-title-and-date-when-printing-web-page-with-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I remove the URL from my print css, so the web address doesn't print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192806/can-i-remove-the-url-from-my-print-css-so-the-web-address-doesnt-print)

Comment: I know right. But how if I just want to see the form only, not the URL? everytime the page appear.

Comment: @Iscmaro, all I want is to display the page with no URL. I just include printing the page, just for my example.

Comment: My question is all about, removing the URL on the page. not on printing the page. I just make it as an example. Thank you ;)

Comment: You should use AJAX to get the data from add_form.php. You can then use ajax to submit the form data and your URL will not change using AJAX.

Comment: Hi @AhmadGulzar, actually I already tried that one. But my requirement is to open a popup page or new page with the form I created with no URL in it. Is it possible to disable the URL wherein it will be removed or will not display everytime the page with form displayed?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774211/change-url-of-already-opened-popup

Comment: But still, there's a link/URL right? The link http://www.canop.org will just be replaced by http://www.google.com. But still the URL is still there. :(

Answer (score 1):

To modify current URL you can use :

1.[The pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) if you want to add a new modified URL to history entries.

2.[The replaceState() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) if you want to update/replace current history entry

```
window.history.pushState({}, document.title, "/" + NewURL );
```