# Opening a new window from dhtmlxgrid avoiding pop up blockers

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx, adblock

The reading of this [Avoid browser popup blockers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587677/172277) confirm my feelings that add blocker does simply allow popup that are opened by a user generated event.

I'm using dhtmlxgrid and get notified from a user click over one cell through the "onRowSelect" event but calling raise a problem with Firefox and Chrome ad blocker :

```
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Any idea or magic solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Dhtmlx Window component? because that call window.open() is pure JS call.

You may try to create a DhtmlxWindow object that is a DIV and it should not be blocked, I used this before and never got problems.

Here's a simple INIT guide to use dhtmlx Window.

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxWindows/samples/01_init/01_minimal_init.html

Comment: This is not related with my problem I want to open the link not to have some JavaScript implementation of windows.

Comment: Perhaps you should try changing the event to onrowdblclicked() or something similar that requires user interaction. When the user perform an interaction with the browser it normally does not block the new window. It's worth testing.