# Avoid popping blocking when calling window.open from .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select menu, for which I have the following code:

```
$('#sister-site-menu').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val()) {
    window.open($(this).val(), '_blank');
  }
});
```

This however causes the popup blocker to be invoked in Chrome. I'm sure I've seen sites do this before, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2587692/1273830

Answer (score 1):

You can safely remove the 'blank'-part. Try this:

```
$('#sister-site-menu').on('change',function(){
  if ($(this).val()) {
    window.open($(this).val());
  }
});
```

If that does not work, I see no other way around this.

Comment: Unfortunately that still invokes the popup blocker. Thanks anyway.