# Chrome window.open after ajax request acts like popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I have a situation where, when a user pushes a button I perform an ajax request, and then use the result of the ajax request to generate a URL which I want to open in a new tab. However, in chrome when I call window.open in the success handler for the ajax request, it opens in a new window like a popup (and is blocked by popup-blockers).  My guess is that since the the success code is asynchronous from the click handling code that chrome thinks it wasn't triggered by a click, even though it is causally related to a click. Is there any way to prevent this without making the ajax request synchronous?

**EDIT**
Here is some minimal code that demonstrates this behaviour:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {'json': JSON.stringify({
            url:'http://google.com'})},
        success: function(data) {
            window.open(data.url,'_blank');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ESMUA/2/

One note of clarification: I am more conerned about it opening in a separate window rather than a tab, than I am about it being blocked by a popup blocker.

Comment: How does the button code look like?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to add

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

#### Edit

Well, I don't think you can get around popup-blockers when opening a page that's not the immediate result of a user action (i.e. not async).

You could try something like this though, it should look like a user action to a popup-blocker:

```
var $a = $('<a>', {
        href: url,
        target: '_blank' 
    });

$(document.body).append($a);
$a.click();
```

#### Edit 2

Looks like you're better of keeping things sync.

As long as the new window is "same origin" you have some power to manipulate it with JS.

```
$('#a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var wi = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');

    setTimeout(function(){ // async
        wi.location.href = 'http://google.com';
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: that is what I am using

Comment: Edited my answer with a different solution. Sorry for assuming jQuery

Comment: unfortunately, the click event doesn't actually trigger the link (although javascript event handlers are called). This is probably disallowed for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-pop-up-blockers

Comment: Edit 2 works, although it may may not be a great experience for the user if the ajax request takes a long time to respond, it should work fine for my purposes though.

Comment: Edit 2 worked for me. I still prefer the user staring a white window instead of locked browser due to sync ajax call..

Answer (score 14):

Try adding async: false. It should be working

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {'json': JSON.stringify({
        url:'http://google.com'})},
    success: function(data) {
        window.open(data.url,'_blank');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Yeah this makes chrome treat it like a user action, well done!

Comment: Yes, but it locks the browser until the request is finished. Thats the dark side of sync requests... I use those in very extreme situations.

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me was:

```
var win = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');

myrepository.postmethod('myserviceurl', myArgs)
.then(function(result) {
    win.location.href = 'http://yourtargetlocation.com/dir/page';
});
```

You open the new window tab before the sync call while you're still in scope, grab the window handle, and then re-navigate once you receive the ajax results in the promise.

Answer (score 9):

The answer posted by @pstenstrm above (Edit 2) mostly works, but I added just one line to it to make the solution more elegant. The ajax call in my case was taking more than a second and the user facing a blank page posed a problem. The good thing is that there is a way to put HTML content in the new window that we've just created.

e.g:

```
$('#a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var wi = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
    $(wi.document.body).html("<p>Please wait while you are being redirected...</p>");

    setTimeout(function(){ // async
        wi.location.href = 'http://google.com';
    }, 500);
});
```

This fills the new tab with the text "Please wait while you are being redirected..." which seems more elegant than the user looking at a blank page for a second. I wanted to post this as the comment but don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Clever, but it doesn't seem to work in the latest Firefox. Solution is probably to setup a static "You are being redirected" page since about:blank is apparently not mutable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way. If your tab/window has been blocked by a pop-blocker in FF and IE6 SP2 then window.open will return the value null.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#FAQ

> How can I tell when my window was blocked by a popup blocker? With the
>   built-in popup blockers of Mozilla/Firefox and Internet Explorer 6
>   SP2, you have to check the return value of window.open(): it will be
>   null if the window wasn't allowed to open. However, for most other
>   popup blockers, there is no reliable way.