# How can I prevent popup blocking after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a JS project where I need for some popups, the problem is that when the popup is being made after an ajax call then the browser will block it but if I make it directly when the user clicking it's working well.

The browser will block this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url
}).done(function(data) {
    showPopup();
});
```

While the browser will let this:

```
$('#but').click(function(evt) {
    showPopup();
});
```

[The code on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7IHeqlurxr8xAWLzrItH?p=preview)

Comment: launch the popup at the start of ajax, update it at finish.

Comment: please up in http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: have you considered lightboxes or modals, or is that not an option?

Comment: @dandavis, I will consider that solution if couldn't find another one.

Comment: @Abdul Ahmad, that's not an option, I need popups.

Comment: you won't find another one, unless you use sync ajax: the call to window.open needs an interaction event in the call stack or it won't fire. your popup should say something like "loading..." at first, and then update once the data is available.

Comment: [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822711/jquery-window-open-in-ajax-success-being-blocked)

Comment: You will have a world of trouble trying to generate a new tab or modal dialog without if being triggered directly from a user interaction. Your best bet is to go with using a internal popup/div style or changing how you generate the popup..

Comment: @dandavis, you were right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

in browser block popup

please test

```
$('#ajax_but').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'data.json'
  }).done(function() {
    popup();
  });
});
```

or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007592/chrome-window-open-after-ajax-request-acts-like-popup)

Comment: I'm not really using **$.ajax** I just put it to give a simple example, I'm using **Restangular**