# Why is my URL called in JavaScript opening as pop-up

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, popup

Browser settings vary for allowing popups and I want my URL which is called within a JavaScript function to open in a new tab and not be considered a popup.I am opening the url as:

`window.open(my_global_link,'_blank');`

In IE and FireFox, when I click on the image I get a notification `Pop-up blocked` and only by `Allowing pop-up for the site` the URL would open in a separate tab. How can I make it open in a separate tab and not consider it a pop-up?

Comment: Just check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-pop-up-blockers

Answer (score 0):

It is a browser setting . try  finding navigation options for new tabs in the browser you are using and set it to open in a new tab instead off a new window.