# window.open on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load a window when the page is loaded. If I try to open the window using a button the code works.

I iam using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
window.open ('http://google.com/', 'newwindow', config='height=720,width=1064, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no');
});
```

However, it is not load the window.

Any suggestion?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.open('http://google.com/', 'newwindow', config = 'height=720,width=1064, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no');
  $('.open_webmail').click(function() {
    window.open('http://google.com/', 'newwindow', config = 'height=720,width=1064, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no');
  });
});
```

```css
.open_webmail {
  background-color: rgba(0, 124, 255, 0.7);
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
.open_webmail:hover {
  background-color: rgba(163, 0, 255, 0.7);
  color: #c5c5c5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="open_webmail">Login</button>
```

Comment: Add `setTimeout` in document ready

Comment: did you check your popup blocker ?

Comment: `Blocked opening 'http://google.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.`

Comment: @Su4p is right. I created fiddle without any change and I was notified about popup

Comment: on my browser is not working

Comment: also tried  setTimeout(function(){window.open ('http://google.com/', 'newwindow', config='height=720,width=1064, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no');}, 100); --- not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `$(window).ready()` also check your pop-up settings, maybe it's being blocked. Because your code works on js fiddle, I tested it.

Comment: thanks had pop up blocked. Is there a way to force a window to not be blocked?

Comment: There may be some hackish way to do it in some specific browser but the general rule is that you can't get around pop-up blockers. I would recommend learning how pop-up blockers work from the behavioral point of view more than the technical and decide if it is necessary for you to force an unwanted pop-up on your users. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-pop-up-blockers