# how to avoid popup blockers using javascript when auto submitting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to redirect new window after form auto submission but being blocked by the different browsers' pop-up blockers? 
       without any click event If auto submission happened then how to redirect new window without popup blockers.

```
<form method = "post" action="securedurl" target="_blank" name="f1">
document.f1.submit()
</form>
```

Comment: If you could avoid popup blockers, then all the popup writers would use that method, and popup blockers wouldn't be useful.

Comment: Did you try with `submit` button ?

Comment: Why do you have Javascript inside a `<form>` instead of inside `<script>`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but still, even today I get the occasional pop-up despite having a blocker. So there have to be some best practices or tricks out there to maximize your chances of not being blocked.

Comment: Here's an old post that deals with it. Relevance to modern day browsers unknown. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers Generally I would guess that the "only open a pop-up as a direct result of user action" still holds true. Pop-up location origin may play a part as well.

Comment: I want to auto submit that's why I have Javascript inside a <form> instead of inside <script>

Comment: Please tell me any alternate solution to avoid popup blockers