# Html href attribute on the condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to `web-development`. I am using `angular-js` .Here , I have a functionality like , when I click on a button then I get a response from back-end , If that is true then I am changing that button to download button. So, after clicking on this, I am doing an ajax call , with it I get a `url`, with which I can download a respective file. So, Here I am using a `href` to download the file.So, My concern is when I click on download that time only it should get that url and also by using `href` should download a file.

My code is  like -

**HTML -**

```
<button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title= "{{ isAvaliable ? 'Download' : 'click to track'}}" ng-disabled="!file.processed" data-ng-click="performAction(file.attributes.name,file.attributes.cn, isAvaliable)">
         <a ng-href="{{url}}" target="_blank" ></a>
        <i ng-class="isAvaliable ? 'fa fa-download' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-text-width'" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.performAction  = function(fileName, cn, isAvaliable) {
                        if(isAvaliable) {
                             $scope.downloadfile(fileName);
                        } else {
                            $scope.moveTofolder(fileName,cn);
                        }
  };

$scope.downloadfile = function(fileName) {
                    uploadService.downloadtracker(fileName)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.url = response.data;

                        },
                        function (error) {

                        })
                        .finally(function () {
                                                       }
                        );

           };

$scope.moveTofolder = function(fileName,cn) {
  // Here also I am calling some service and  I am getting response .\
  /// Here I am changing the button 
  $scope.isAvaliable = true;        
}
```

So, Here I am getting some problems, because of the href and the downloadButton . So, How can I call a function on download click and get the URl and at the same time get that url and use it in the href so that It can download the file as well.  `Href` and `downloadButton` are for the same purpose.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind to remove the horizontal scollbars and fix your spelling?

Comment: Chech the Href atribute "download"... it makes a link to be downloaded (the href src) into your pc.

Comment: $scope.performAction function also have download function call. And why you call both functions.

Comment: I am calling it because See, I have  a button on which at start it is like track so then it will call a moveTofolder method. then On this if it successfully moved then it will change the same track button to download button. Now On this click, First I need to get the Url and then I want to download the file.So, I want to have both actions on the same click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below. Don't mingle `<a> and <button>` because you have button click and also anchor click event.

```
<a ng-href="{{url}}" ng-click="Download()" ></a>

$scope.Download = function(){
//some other code
window.open($scope.url);
}



 <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title= "{{ isAvaliable ? 'Download' : 'click to track'}}" ng-disabled="!file.processed" data-ng-click="performAction(file.attributes.name,file.attributes.cn, isAvaliable);downloadfile
(url)">

        <i ng-class="isAvaliable ? 'fa fa-download' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-text-width'" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Actually the problem is that the same button gets turned into the download button.

Comment: First I am calling download method to get the url, and then I am using that url as  a link in the href.

Comment: Then use ng-show/hide .. Which button you need after get the link, just show it

Comment: We don't need two ng-click. You can give more function call in single ng-click. see my update button code

Comment: It is downloading a file two times now.

Comment: As per your code. ng-click button download happening also <a href> download happening .  So two time. Are you try with ng-show/hide not working try with ng-if

Comment: Working fine  , but only concern is about window.open($scope.url) , It is changing a window for microseconds .

Comment: I can't get.. A new window or tab is opened. If a window with the same name already exists, the existing window is refreshed

Comment: It just,  for fraction of second it opens a new window and then after download gets back to the original one.

Comment: try  window.open(url , '_blank'); or  window.open(url , '_tab');

Comment: Thanks a lot for this , do you have any idea about the popup blocker? Because when I click on download then I need to allow the popups then it will download.

Comment: Pop-ups are blocked only when if the browser suspects non-user is initiating the pop-up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add download attribute in your button

```
<button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title= "{{ isAvaliable ? 'Download' : 'click to track'}}" ng-disabled="!file.processed" data-ng-click="performAction(file.attributes.name,file.attributes.cn, isAvaliable)" ng-click=“downloadfile
({{url}})”>
         <!— <a ng-href="{{url}}" target="_blank" ></a> —>
        <i ng-class="isAvaliable ? 'fa fa-download' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-text-width'" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Add $http in controller

```
$scope.downloadfile = function(fileName) {
                //here I am calling a service and I am getting a responce which contains a url.
            $scope.$emit('download-start');

            $http.get(fileName).then(function(response) {
                $scope.$emit('downloaded', response.data);
            });

                    $scope.url =  responce.data;
               }
```

Hope this help you

Comment: So, Here you have added ng-click two times.

Comment: You can add ng-click to a tag as well

Comment: I have updated my downloadFile methods, It like that I am not getting waht you want to say.