# How to avoid popup blocker when opening a new tab on a button click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm programmimg a web application using knockout.js. There I'm trying to open a new tab on a button click. While it actually works fine on localhost, the popup blocker complains once I deploy the application. Is there any way to avoid the popup blocker considering these circumstances?

**Button in the HTML-Code**

```
<button data-bind="click:openNewTab"
        type="button">
    Open new tab
</button>
```

**Piece of JavaScript-Code of the ViewModel which is used from the HTML file mentioned above**

```
self.openNewTab = function ()
{
    var newTabUrl = "https://www.stackoverflow.com";
    window.open(newTabUrl, '_blank');
};
```

Comment: If you think about this for a minute, if there was a way.  Then popup blocker's would be useless, as the people wanting to show unsolicited pop-up's would use this technique too.  Best option is ask your users to create an exception in there popup blocker, or maybe alter your application to maybe use HTML tabs & IFrames.

Comment: Read this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers)

Comment: had a similar situation believe I did if !(window.open) then I unhid a link with a message that said you pop up blocker is enabled please click link to continue,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid browser popup blockers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers)