# Popups are not suppressed if the delay <= 1000 ms

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open, popup-blocker, browser-security

I've tested on various browsers executing code snippet below and they have all get blocked by default.

```
setTimeout(() => window.open('https://google.com'), 1001);
```

But if the delay is `<= 1000` it can successfully open a new tab/window.

Why?

Comment: popups need to be launched as the result of a user action.

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers