# Generate plot as png and show it in a new tab

Tags: r, shiny, hosting, shiny-server

In my application, I create plots depending on my users ui inputs and the datasets they upload. I would now like to add the functionality to show the plot in a new tab rather than just providing a normal `downloadHandler`.

Here is a simplified version of my current implementation. (*Note: Both examples posted here do not work in the RStudio browser. Use an external browser instead*)

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

addResourcePath(prefix = "plot", tempdir())

save_plot <- function(input, path) {
  n <- input$n
  df <- data.frame(x = 1:n, y = cumsum(rnorm(n)))
  gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
  ggsave(gg, filename = path)
}

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    sliderInput("n", "n", 100, 1000, 500),
    actionButton("newtab", "open plot in new tab")
  ),
  function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$newtab, {
      save_plot(input, file.path(tempdir(), "plot.png"))
      shinyjs::runjs("window.open('plot/plot.png', '_blank')")
    })
  }
)
```

My issue with this implementation is the popup blocker which (rather quietly) stops the new tabs from opening. I don't want to make my users disable their popup blockers just to use my web application.

Another thing I tried was to use a link and listen to the clicks like so

```
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    sliderInput("n", "n", 100, 1000, 500),
    tags$a(id = "link", href = "plot/plot.png", target = "_blank", 
           "open plot in new tab")
  ),
  function(input, output, session){
    shinyjs::onclick("link", {
      save_plot(input, file.path(tempdir(), "plot.png"))
    })
  }
)
```

Here, the first plot looks good, but when pressing a second time, the old plot gets shown because `save_plot` takes longer than the creation of a new tab. Also, I would like to have the option to style the ui element that triggers the new tab rather than being limited to a link.

I feel like I'm getting really close to a satisfying solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could be useful for the first issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I need to find a way to invoke `save_plot` and `window.open` from an `onclick` event in javascript for the "direct user action" clause.