# Blocking popup in mobile view securionpay

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway

I have implemented demo for securepay from reference link [https://securionpay.com/docs/checkout#custom-integration](http://Checkout)

I have used custom integration as below

```
<script src="https://securionpay.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        SecurionpayCheckout.key = 'key';
        SecurionpayCheckout.success = function (result) {
            // handle successful payment (e.g. send payment data to your server)
        };
        SecurionpayCheckout.error = function (errorMessage) {
            // handle integration errors (e.g. send error notification to your server)
        };

        $('#payment-button').click(function () {
            SecurionpayCheckout.open({
                checkoutRequest: 'xyz=',
                name: 'SecurionPay',
                description: 'Checkout example'
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="payment-button">Payment button</button>
```

Here integration working pefect.but when i want open popup on load page instead of clicking button then its block by browser in mobile view.so how to prevent to block using JavaScript without allowing from browser.
Getting error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open Checkout using onload. User must explicitly request the popup otherwise browser will block it. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers) question for more information.

Comment: can you give example for explicitly request

Comment: For example snippet in your question. Checkout open after user click a button.

Comment: in my requirement is on load open.not click button