# window.location.href not showing content in Edge

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, blob, microsoft-edge

I am generating a .pdf in ASP.NET MVC and sending it to Angular 5 service. The requirement is to have it opened in new tab without downloading.

When the .pdf is generated, I send it to front end as a `FileResult` conatining a `byte` array and `"application/pdf"` content type.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40283785/2975357) answer pointed me to the following solution:

```
getPdf(): void {  
    let newTab = window.open(); //opens new tab immediately to avoid popup blocking 

    this.pdfService.getPdf().subscribe(res => {

      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res); //Blob from the backend
      newTab.location.href = fileURL;
    });
  }
```

This solution works on Chrome and Mozilla, but not in **Edge**. When I try the functionality in Edge, the tab that is opened never shows the content. Furthermore, I get the following error in console:

> [object Error]: {description: "Permission denied", message:
>   "Permission denied", number: -2146828218, stack: "Error: Permission
>   denied at Anonymous function (eval code:312:13) at
>   SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub (eval code:244:13) at
>   SafeSubscriber.prototype.next (eval code:191:17) at
>   Subscriber.prototype._next (eval code:132:9) at
>   Subscriber.prototype.next (eval code:96:13) at
>   MapSubscriber.prototype._next (eval code:88:9) at
>   Subscriber.prototype.next (eval code:96:13) at
>   FilterSubscriber.prototype._next (eval code:92:13) at
>   Subscriber.prototype.next (eval code:96:13) at
>   MergeMapSubscriber.prototype.notifyNext (eval code:156:13)"}