# Set location.href on new _blank tab asynchronously not working on MS Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I want to open new tab using `_authTab = window.open('', '_blank');` an set it's url asynchronously
for example `setTimeout(() => _authTab!.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 2000);`. On chrome everything works fine: blank page is openned and after 2 seconds `https://stackoverflow.com/` is loaded.

```
function setUrlAsync(): AsyncAction {
  let _authTab: Window | null;
  return async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
    try {
      let authTab: AuthWindow;
      _authTab = window.open('', '_blank'); // A new window has to be be opened synchronously to avoid pop-up blockers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-popup-blockers)
      setTimeout(() => _authTab!.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 2000);
    } catch (error) {
      authActions.callbackUrlNotReceived({ error });
      throw error;
    }
  };
}
```

Ms Edge throws an error causing new tab stays `_blank`

```
[object Error]: {description: "Permission denied", message: "Permission denied", nr@seenError: true, number: -2146828218, stack: "Error: Permission denied at Anonymous function (https://52f62d4b.ngrok.io/:149596:15) at nrWrapper (Unknown script code:1:16969)"}
description: "Permission denied"
message: "Permission denied"
nr@seenError: true
number: -2146828218
stack: "Error: Permission denied at Anonymous function (https://52f62d4b.ngrok.io/:149596:15) at nrWrapper (Unknown script code:1:16969)"

__proto__: Error
```

**EDIT**
Webpage is being used inside `iframe`

```
  <iframe 
      allow="accelerometer *; ambient-light-sensor *; autoplay *; camera *; encrypted-media *; fullscreen *; geolocation *; gyroscope *; magnetometer *; microphone *; midi *; payment *; picture-in-picture *; speaker *; usb *; vibrate *; vr *"
      sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts" 
      src="....">
  </iframe>
```

Comment: Can you please at least explain negatives?

Answer (score 1):

Edge probably considers that `''` url at `window.open('', '_blank')` as being in a different domain. Reference: [WHATWG same-origin policy](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#same-origin) 
Try opening a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

The url can be set in new open page on Edge if we remove the `sandbox` attributes.

**A.html**

```
<iframe allow="accelerometer *; ambient-light-sensor *; autoplay *; camera *; encrypted-media *; fullscreen *; geolocation *; gyroscope *; magnetometer *; microphone *; midi *; payment *; picture-in-picture *; speaker *; usb *; vibrate *; vr *"
        src="B.html">
</iframe>
```

**B.html**

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="opennew()" />
<script>
    function opennew() {
        var _authTab = window.open('', '_blank');
        setTimeout(() => _authTab.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 2000);
    }
</script>
```

From the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Browser_compatibility), we can see that many values of `sandbox` are not supported by Edge. So this might be the reason why the url can't be set on Edge when we use iframe with `sandbox` attribute.

Comment: Good point, but sandbox with those exact props has to be there.

Comment: Then I think you could only try to load the url synchronously on Edge. I tried a lot of combinations of `sandbox` values and the result is always showing error with "Permission denied" on Edge.